# How to extract all links from pdf file?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

By standard, links are hiding in Annotations (section 12.5.6.5 from specifications). It is easy to extract address from there: [Extracting links to pages in another PDF from PDF using Python or other method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973463/extracting-links-to-pages-in-another-pdf-from-pdf-using-python-or-other-method)
But very often links are presented not like special objects in document, but as plain text like "http://blah-blah.com". How do I extract not only links from annotations, but links from text itself? I can search through the whole text and finding words like "http://", but is there more optimal solution? PDF editors are highlighting text-links too, how do they know that this piece of text is hyperlink?

Comment: They don't know, they guess. You will have to do the same (and hope you can do a better job).

Comment: I suppose that you downvoted his question for the reason you incorrectly specified above. They do not "guess", they detect urls. It's a valid question.  Here's an example mechanism how they might do it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/

Answer (score 30):

I've just made `pdfx`, a small tool for exactly this job: to download all PDFs from a given PDF. It's written in Python and released as [open source](https://github.com/metachris/pdfx) under the GPLv3 license: http://www.metachris.com/pdfx

You can use `pdfx` tool to show all PDF URLs, all URLs (with `-v`), as well as download all referenced PDFs (using `-d`):

```
$ pdfx https://weakdh.org/imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf -d ./
Reading url 'https://weakdh.org/imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf'...
Saved pdf as './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf'
Document infos:
- CreationDate = D:20150821110623-04'00'
- Creator = LaTeX with hyperref package
- ModDate = D:20150821110805-04'00'
- PTEX.Fullbanner = This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) kpathsea version 6.1.1
- Producer = pdfTeX-1.40.14
- Title = Imperfect Forward Secrecy: How Diffie-Hellman Fails in Practice
- Trapped = False
- Pages = 13

Analyzing text...
- URLs: 49
- URLs to PDFs: 17

JSON summary saved as './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf.infos.json'

Downloading 17 referenced pdfs...
Created directory './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs'
Downloaded 'http://cr.yp.to/factorization/smoothparts-20040510.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/smoothparts-20040510.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35517.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35517.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35514.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35514.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35519.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35519.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35522.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35522.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35509.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35509.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35528.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35528.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35513.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35513.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35533.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35533.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35551.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35551.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35527.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35527.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35520.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35520.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35526.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35526.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35515.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35515.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35529.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35529.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://cryptome.org/2013/08/spy-budget-fy13.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/spy-budget-fy13.pdf'...
Downloaded 'http://www.spiegel.de/media/media-35671.pdf' to './imperfect-forward-secrecy.pdf-referenced-pdfs/media-35671.pdf'...
```

You can install it with `$ easy_install -U pdfx`.

Under the hood, pdfx uses [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2), a Python library to read PDF content and then a [regular expression to match all urls](https://github.com/metachris/pdfx/blob/master/libs/urlmarker.py).

Comment: Only finds pdfs within pdfs. Not urls.

Comment: You can run `pdfx` with the `-v` flag to see all links instead of just the pdfs.

Comment: Ok, in that case it is very useful! +1

Comment: pdf.get_references_as_dict() did all the job for me. Thank you!

Comment: Looks tantalisingly useful. However: it gets either links or links text, but not both 2gether. It even gets a dict of links. Yet doesnt include text with each link. The author, having gone this far, mightv gone the last few yards. I found pdf.get_references_as_dict() didn't extract a dict of links but a dict containing a single list of links, indexed by the string 'url'. (Sorry @ChrisHager: need to dig up my Github login, so have not made a useful report directly). HOWEVER: ***** this is the only tool I cd find that wd simply get all links, even among the many pdf readers *****

Answer (score 23):

```
strings "somePDFfile.pdf" | grep http
```

This works even better if you use `pdftk` to uncompress it first (credits: [Ben Stern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8657995/ben-stern)):

```
pdftk in.pdf cat output out.pdf uncompress; strings out.pdf | grep -i http
```

Answer (score 2):

An updated version to extract hyperlinks from pdf with the latest pyPDF2 3.0.0, which has significant API changes. Works fine here as of today (31 Jan 2023):

```
import PyPDF2
import sys

# @input : Path of the PDF file
argPDFPath = sys.argv[1]
print("First argument:", argPDFPath)

# Open the PDF file
with open(argPDFPath, "rb") as file:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    
    # Loop through each page in the PDF
    for page_num in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[page_num]
        
        # Extract the annotations from the page
        annotations = page["/Annots"]
        
        # Loop through each annotation
        for annot in annotations:
            hyperlink = annot.get_object()["/A"].get_object()["/URI"]        
            print(hyperlink)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just make it a bit trickier

```
pdftk the_file_with_links.pdf cat 5-10 output - | strings | grep http\:\/\/www\.thedesiredplace\.com\/ | sed -e 's/\/URI\ (/ wget --no-check-certificate /g' -e 's/)//g'
```

That is, splitted and explained, get the pages with the links (change 5-10 to the range of pages you need)

```
pdftk the_file_with_links.pdf cat 5-10 output -
```

next, get all the strings from the pdf pages

```
strings
```

then, separate those that contains the desired web links

```
grep http\:\/\/www\.thedesiredplace\.com\/
```

and clean the strings from undesired chars, replace with wget command

```
sed -e 's/\/URI\ (/ wget --no-check-certificate /g' -e 's/)//g'
```

Last thing is copy and past this into your command line :)